# Extract feelds as key value from a json object in mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mariadb

Hello I want to extract the different field values of a json object as key value pairs, but I'm not able to do that.

I tried this

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(chapters, '$[*].Id', '$[*].Name') AS rec 
  FROM `Novels` 
 WHERE 1
```

but it result looks like this
`["1","first Name","2","second name"]`

any idea on how to convert it to something like this
`{"1":"first Name","2":"second name"}`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. Include the sample data you have in the colum.

Comment: Looks like i made a mistake....it's actually MariaDB that my server is using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the result, the concerned value of the chapters column should be

```
'[ {"Id":"1","Name":"first name"}, {"Id":"2","Name":"second name"} ]'
```

`JSON_EXTRACT()` can be applied for each element of the array in order to determine **Id** values as **keys** part, and **Name** values as **values** part.

And then, `JSON_UNQUOTE()` can be applied to get rid of double-quotes while generating rows for each individual array elements. `JSON_OBJECTAGG` is used to aggregate all those extracted objects at the last step provided that MariaDB version is 10.5+:

```
WITH n AS
(
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS rn, 
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(chapters, CONCAT('$[',@i-1,'].Id'))) AS js_id,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(chapters, CONCAT('$[',@i-1,'].Name'))) AS js_name
  FROM information_schema.tables  
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @i := 0, chapters FROM `Novels` ) n
 WHERE @i < JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(chapters, '$[*]'))
)
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(js_id,js_name) AS Result
  FROM n
```

A Workaround might be given for DB version prior to 10.5 as

```
SELECT CONCAT('{', 
       GROUP_CONCAT( 
                    REPLACE(
                            REPLACE( JSON_OBJECT(js_id,js_name) , '}', '') 
                            , '{', '')
                    )        
        , '}') AS Result
  FROM n
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=a6958e1f6946762b700e294ccd569f4e)</kbd>

Comment: you're wlecome @user2219222

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `json_table()` to unnest the array to rows (available in MySQL 8 only) then aggregation:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (
        select json_objectagg('id', x.id, 'name', x.name)
        from json_table(
            t.chapter,
            '$[*]' 
            columns (
                id int path '$.Id',
                name varchar(50) path '$.Name'
            )
        ) as x
    ) as obj
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Unfortunately my server seems to be using MariaDB

Comment: `JSON_TABLE()` is now in MariaDB as of version 10.6.0.